# Uninstalled asterisk, still gets email about error logs

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, cron

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: error accessing /var/log/asterisk: No such file or directory
error: asterisk:1 glob failed for /var/log/asterisk/*_log
error: found error in /var/log/asterisk/debug /var/log/asterisk/messages /var/log/asterisk/full /var/log/asterisk/*_log , skipping
error: stat of /var/log/asterisk/debug failed: No such file or directory
error: stat of /var/log/asterisk/messages failed: No such file or directory
error: stat of /var/log/asterisk/full failed: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

I get this email everyday and i'm sick of it. I looked around at some files with nano and i didn't see anywhere to remove it. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and i don't know how to remove this from running everyday. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the logrotate file for this application is probably located under the directory /etc/logrotate.d/.  You can then edit the offending file, probably by commenting out  the references to /var/log/asterisk/*_log.  Or you could move the offending file outside this directory into something like /etc/logrotate.d.save just in case you might need it again.

Comment: Just did that. Guess i'll wait till the next day and not see the email now. That seemed simple. Learnt something new.

Comment: Awesome it worked. No annoying emails anymore!

Answer (score 1):

You need to *completely* remove asterisk, by purging it (`--purge` option to either dpkg or apt-get/aptitude command, as required) rather than just uninstalling it.  That will remove the logrotate fragment that's causing the problem.